# Unable to import Numpy in VS Code

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I am switching the IDEs (from Spyder to VS Code). Howeve, the script that I used to run in Spyder throws an error when I run it on VS Code :

[image: Error picture]

I followed these solutions [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61935283/running-numpy-using-anaconda-and-vs-code), [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962703/how-to-get-numpy-working-properly-in-anaconda-python-3-7-6), [SO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360460/how-to-start-visual-studio-code-within-anaconda-env): tried to launch the VS code by Anaconda prompt or uninstall and reinstall numpy and reran the script but the same error was still popped up.

Anyone can help me ?

Here is the output of conda env list :
[image: Picture]

Comment: There should be an `activate.ps1` script, try running that instead of just `activate`. Might help.

Comment: Upgrade `numpy`; recent version is `1.20.3`…

Comment: @Diptangsu Goswami : What does that mean ? Sorry, I am new to python.

Comment: @JosefZ I use pip install numpy --upgrade but it said that my numpy version (1.19.2) is the newest one.

Comment: @JosefZ I think `1.20` is not yet available via conda

Comment: run `conda env list` and show us the output. You need to be activating one of the available envs that has numpy installed in it. I'd guess that the env you're using is `base`. Considering my assumption is correct, just run `conda activate base`. Then, run your code in the same terminal.

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami : you can find the output in the 2nd image. I ran conda activate base also and reran the code however it still throws that error.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't activated the conda environment.

You can find it does not have the environment name before the

> PS D:\Desktop\work...

It should be like:

> (base)PS D:\Desktop\work...

You can find it in your second picture.

If you haven't activated the conda environment, it will cause the `mkl` problem.

> User Warning:mkl-service package failed to import...

> Importing the numpy C-extension failed.

It's not a problem of you haven't installed the numpy package.

Try to run `conda init` command in any terminal. It maybe helpful.